# Fetch, authenticate, and download a post-install script on FreeBSD

Tags: system-installation, freebsd, authentication

I'm on a fresh FreeBSD install and want to download and run a post-install script from a private BitBucket repo. My fetch attempt returns an authentication error:

```
~# fetch "https://bitbucket.org/me/server/raw/abcde...xyz/post-install.sh"

Certificate verification failed for /C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV CA-1
34380949368:error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed:/usr/src/secure/lib/libssl/../../../crypto/openssl/ssl/s3_clnt.c:1180:
fetch: https://bitbucket.org/me/server/raw/abcde...xyz/post-install.sh: Authentication error
```

Is there a way to authenticate (from command-line or prompt for username/password) and download the file without installing additional packages?

**Edit 1:**

The following `wget` commands *do* work:

```
~# wget --no-check-certificate --user myname --password mypass "https://bitbucket.org/me/server/raw/abcde...xyz/post-install.sh"
~# wget --no-check-certificate "https://myname:mypass@bitbucket.org/me/server/raw/abcde...xyz/post-install.sh"
```

However, the following `fetch` still fails:

```
~# fetch --no-verify-peer "https://myname:mypass@bitbucket.org/me/server/raw/abcde...xyz/post-install.sh"
```

But it doesn't throw an error, it just downloads the wrong file---an HTML BitBucket login form.

**Edit 2:**

As @SteveWills deduced, BitBucket doesn't care much for `fetch`; changing the user-agent allowed authentication to work:

```
~# fetch --no-verify-peer --user-agent "Wget/1.16 (freebsd10.0)" "https://myname:mypass@bitbucket.org/me/server/raw/abcde...xyz/post-install.sh"
```

Comment: Perhaps Bitbucket does some processing of the user agent and knows about wget and uses the http auth in that case, but doesn't know about fetch? Perhaps the --user-agent flag to fetch will help.

Comment: @SteveWills You're exactly right, changing the user-agent did the trick, thanks! (Though it seems kinda gross on BitBucket's part.)

Comment: Glad to hear it! And yes, depending on user agent is gross, but it happens all the time. File a bug with BitBucket to at least get them to add the user agent for fetch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the --no-verify-peer option will fix the certification verification error. If you want to authentication, just add the user/pass to the url like https://user:password@host.domain/path

Comment: Hmm, either fetch or BitBucket don't seem to like that auth url.